# Ошибка в формат патрона для Yandex.Tank

Tags: яндекс-танк

Переписал генератор патронов под свои задачи. При запуске танка степпер выкидывает с следующей ошибкой:

> 15:04:10 INFO: Loading ammo from './ammo.txt' 15:04:10 INFO: Using
>   AmmoFileReader ammo reader 15:04:10 INFO: Exception: Traceback (most
>   recent call last):   File
>   "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/yandextank/core/consoleworker.py",
>   line 263, in perform_test
>       self.core.plugins_prepare_test()   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/yandextank/core/tankcore.py", line
>   303, in plugins_prepare_test
>       plugin.prepare_test()   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/yandextank/plugins/Phantom/plugin.py",
>   line 112, in prepare_test
>       self.config = self.phantom.compose_config()   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/yandextank/plugins/Phantom/PhantomUtils.py",
>   line 95, in compose_config
>       streams_config += stream.compose_config()   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/yandextank/plugins/Phantom/PhantomUtils.py",
>   line 266, in compose_config
>       self.stepper_wrapper.prepare_stepper()   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/yandextank/stepper/main.py", line
>   206, in prepare_stepper
>       self.**make_stpd_file()   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/yandextank/stepper/main.py", line
>   296, in __make_stpd_file
>       stepper.write(os)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/yandextank/stepper/main.py", line
>   61, in write
>       for missile in self.ammo:   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/yandextank/stepper/format.py", line
>   15, in 
>       return ("%s %s %s\n%s\n" % (len(missile), timestamp, marker, missile) for timestamp, marker, missile in self.af)   File
>   "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/yandextank/stepper/main.py", line
>   48, in 
>       (timestamp, marker or self.marker(missile), missile)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/yandextank/stepper/main.py", line
>   41, in 
>       ammo_stream = (ammo for ammo in (   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/yandextank/stepper/main.py", line
>   42, in 
>       (missile, marker or self.marker(missile))   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/yandextank/stepper/missile.py", line
>   134, in __iter**
>       "Error while reading ammo file. Position: %s, header: '%s', original exception: %s" % (ammo_file.tell(), chunk_header, e))
>   AmmoFileError: Error while reading ammo file. Position: 507, header:
>   'e=&CSRFToken=617c4332-acff-4a13-9ac4-802ebc2a00be', original
>   exception: invalid literal for int() with base 10:
>   'e=&CSRFToken=617c4332-acff-4a13-9ac4-802ebc2a00be'
>
> 15:04:10 ERROR: Error while reading ammo file. Position: 507, header:
>   'e=&CSRFToken=617c4332-acff-4a13-9ac4-802ebc2a00be', original
>   exception: invalid literal for int() with base 10:
>   'e=&CSRFToken=617c4332-acff-4a13-9ac4-802ebc2a00be'

Конфиг фантома:

```
[phantom]
address=%(target1)s
use_caching=0
rps_schedule=step(0, 1000, 100, 10m) line(1000,0,10m)
connection_test=0
ssl=1
ammofile=./ammo.txt
```

Фрагмент ammo.txt:

```
452
POST /search/ajax-results?q=плащик%3A&&page=0&isGrid=0 HTTP/1.1^M
User-Agent: YandexTankPhantom/1.2.3^M
Origin: https://my.site.com^M
Host: my.site.com^M
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate^M
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,ru^M
Accept: */*^M
Cookie: JSESSIONID=4FF4289AF8319D69D6787137CBC0DE35.hybris1p^M
Connection: Close^M
Content-Length: 38^M
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest^M
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded^M
^M
categoryName=&CSRFToken=617c4332-acff-4a13-9ac4-802ebc2a00be^M
^M
471
POST /cart/add/?qty=1&productCodePost=000000000001123654&CSRFToken=2ad5df88-b6c9-47a1-a00c-1cf73e1b2324 HTTP/1.1^M
```

В чем может быть причина?

Comment: Похоже неправильно считается длина запроса например 452 и 471. Длину запроса надо считать с учетом символов перевода строк?

Comment: Длину запроса нужно считать в байтах, так что переводы строк, естественно учитываются (обратите также внимание что в http запросах перевод строк `\r\n`, а вот танк умеет читать и `\n` и исправлять на нужные.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, переносы строки учитываются (кроме первой строки, в которой указано количество байт).
В Вашем случае вместо 452 верным будет 471.

Comment: Да. Действительно. Неправильно считал длину сообщений (т.к. длина считалась до подстановки новых значений куки и CSRF токенов). Алгоритм поправил все работает.